# back compression in skoda Rapid

Tags: compression

I have skoda Rapid 2012, there seems to be a oil leakage. Recently one mechanic said there is back compression in the engine but another said Skodas have back compression and nothing to worry. 
I am not sure who is correct.
There is no drop in power or engine pick up, just at times I feel that engine is hot near the padels.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem- is the oil leak what you are worried about? Or hot air at your feet? Or possible "back compression"?

Comment: I have back compression, but not in my Skoda.  Hanging upside down from my ankles helps a lot.  Did you mean "exhaust back pressure"?  All vehicles have this to some extent.

Comment: I am  more worried about the back compression. It does not throw oil out through Oil dip stick ,just fumes.